# .htaccess equivalent of baseurl?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony1

I'm trying to install Symfony on a shared server and am attempting to duplicate the httpd.conf command:

```
# Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080

# This is the configuration for your project
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/home/sfproject/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/sfproject/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /home/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I need to do so using .htaccess

The redirect portion was done in the root using the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^symfony.mysite.ca [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://symfony.mysite.ca/web/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

For the alias, I've tried using:

```
RewriteBase /
```

but no success.

The main issue is that the index.php file residing in the /web folder uses the /web path in its path to images and scripts.  So instead of

```
href="/css/main.css"  //this would work
```

it uses

```
href="/web/css/main.css"  //this doesn't work, already in the /web/ directory!
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

to prevent urls that refer to actual files from being rewritten, thus preventing the generic rewrite from adding a second `/web` into the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm still left slightly confused.  I understand that I can use your example above to identify if a file doesn't exist.

What RewriteRule can I use that would:
1. Check to see that the file its looking for starts with /web
2. Replace that path with the same path, but chopping the /web off the start.

Is that possible?

Comment: `/web/css/main.css` is an *absolute* path - even if it's referenced from a file in the `/web` directory, since it begins with a `/` it will be loaded relative to the document root, not any subdirectory within it. Thus, my guess is that the problem isn't actually needing to *remove* `/web` from the path, but instead simply prevent your rewriterule that *adds* it from triggering in cases where it's already pointing to the proper file. Hence my suggestion of the conditions, to prevent the rewriterule from triggering when the path is already correct.